# multiple condition in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to write a linq query to check an ID is exist in sql table and If the ID is exist need to check one field is null or not in the same table.

I am new in entity framework ,please help.

Currently doing by like this:-

Here i am selecting by two methods,if the first method returns true i am checking the second method. Based on this value i need to enable/disable a tab.

```
public bool GetCompanyInfoById(int customerId)
        {
            using (var context = new eSmoEntities())
            {
                bool companyExist = context.tm_cmd_company_details.Any(x=>x.com_id.Equals(customerId));
                return companyExist;
            }
        }

        public bool GetGroupForCompany(int customerId)
        {
        using (var context = new eSmoEntities())
            {
                var customer = context.tm_cmd_company_details.Where(x => x.com_id == customerId).Select(x=>x.cmd_group_id).FirstOrDefault();
                return customer != null ? true : false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would help if you show your entity definition and/or a sample query (working or not).  Usually such a condition can be done with a join clause similar to `where new {x.A, x.B} equals new {y.A, y.B}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first to find the entity with the given Id, for example =1.

```
var entity = dbContext.AnyTable.FirstOrDefault(t => where t.Id =1);
if (entity != null)
{

  if (entity.AnyField != null)
  {

   } 
}
```

In this apporach you must use eager loading. If you are using Lazy loading then the entity will be load at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty trivial question, you just need two boolean conditions for your linq query:

```
Context.MyItems.Any(i => i.ID == suppliedID && i.OtherProperty != null)
```

Obviously, this will be easier to answer specifically if you supply your EntityFramework model.

This is only half the problem though; what do you want to do after? Select an item that meets your specifications? Do something if these conditions are met? It appears you need to think through your problem on your own before coming to Stack Overflow and asking for a complete solution for you to copy-paste.